# React Native initial App size is too large

Tags: react-native

I know this question asked before but the solutions provided there is not enough to reduce app size.

I have create a app using `react-native init`. No any third party library added yet. Just a hello world app. but its release build size is 48mb.

After that I used `def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true` it reduced 2Mb and app size become 46MB.

Again I used `def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true` app size reduced to half now its 26MB.

But why just a hello world app in react-native takes 26MB. Its seems quite useless.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "WooVendors",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: without `def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true` the size should be between 25mb to 30 mb , share your apk file so i can check further

Comment: @VinilPrabhu I have managed to get 8mb apk. but Its expanding after install around 25 mb ok let say its not big concern but can't I get apk less than 8 mb.

Comment: i dont think you can get apk of lesser size, i got the least size for my app around 11mb when i used [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

Comment: @VinilPrabhu then tell me how can I create AAB using react-native?

Comment: open android folder in android studion and then build>generate signed apk/bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android App Bundle(aab) will slightly reduce apk size (>=8Mb).

To generate Android App Bundle follow [Official Guide Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)

Answer (score -1):

You are using react native 0.59 in which a new version of JSC is shipped which is faster and 64-bit compatible. To reduce apk size change react native version below 0.59.

[APK file is larger with react-native 0.59](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24154#issuecomment-476761691)

Comment: Downgrading is not gpood solution but thanks for informing about large apk size reason.

Comment: Hey @AbhishekSingh, how did you reduce the size of react native app ran into the same issue.

Comment: @aashirkhan during release you will generate .aab file which is smaller in size.